# Memory leak in windows forms

Tags: winforms, memory-leaks

We have a form formA, and from that form we are adding another form say fromB to this formA. On dispose method i am disposing formA using formA.Dispose(). By this step whether it will dispose all its child forms used in formA or do I need to call the Dispose() method explicitly for each forms and its controls?

Similarly in fromB we are using some list of Windows.Forms.Control and we are not making these lists as null in the Dispose method of formB. Do we need to dispose these list also?

Comment: Typically you don't clutter the code by disposing managed resources. Let the garbage collector take care of it.

Comment: @Ginosaji: but the thing is some issues are reported like memory is goes on increasing when the form is opened and closed for some fifty times or something

Comment: As long as you aren't holding a reference to the forms elsewhere, the garbage collector will take care of it. Alternatively, you could simply reuse a single instance of each fo these forms and `Show`/`Hide` them as necessary.